# Python : How can I check if the content of one entire column of a Dataframe is empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, is-empty

I want to check if one entire column of a dataframe is empty ! So let's say that I have

```
data1 = [12,34,'',678,896]
data2 = ['','','','','']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data1,data2)),columns = ['Data1','Data2'])
print(df)

   Data1 Data2
0     12
1     34
2    
3    678
4    896
```

The column "Data1" has data and the column "Data2" is empty. I tried the function `print(df['Data2'].empty)`, but it returns me false and I don't get why. So how can I verify that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are blank spaces,
it might not be all `''` so it is better to use `regex` here, then we can use [`Series.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [`Series.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html)

```
df['Data2'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).isna().all()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the `Series` is empty by first converting `''(Blank)` to `np.nan` and then `dropna()`:

```
In [2530]: import numpy as np
In [2531]: df.Data2 = df.Data2.replace('', np.nan)

In [2533]: df.Data2.dropna().empty
Out[2533]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometime you'll want to check if multiple columns are empty, and if they are you'll want to know which ones are empty (instead of checking 1 column at a time).

You can do this by:

1. replacing the blank values `''` with `np.nan`
2. checking where the dataframe has null values `.isna()`
3. then check if any of the columns are entirely filled with null values via `.all()`.

Sample data

```
data1 = [12,34,'',678,896]
data2 = ['','','','','']
data3 = ['','','','','']
data4 = [10, '', 11, 6, '']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data1,data2, data3, data4)),columns = ['Data1','Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4'])

print(df)
  Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4
0    12                10
1    34                  
2                      11
3   678                 6
4   896
```

Method

```
out = df.replace('', np.nan).isna().all()

print(out)
Data1    False
Data2     True
Data3     True
Data4    False
dtype: bool
```

In the result `out`, we can see that there are `True` values corresponding to columns that are entirely empty, and `False` values for columns that are **not** entirely empty.

Answer (score 1):

the whitespace is a character too, for this reason you always have false, if you want write this

```
data2 = [None,None,None,None,None]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data1,data2)),columns = ['Data1','Data2'])
print(df)
```

when you check with this:

```
print(df['Data2'].empty)
```

it is return True

Comment: good answer, the problem is that we do not know if it is `None` or `''` or `np.nan`. welcome to stackoverflow