# Check if the barplot made with seaborn in Python actually has bars

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I try to save a figure as a .png file only if the created barplot actually has bars (for some dataframes df there will be no bars)

My attempt was the following

```py
import seaborn as sns
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
gr = sns.barplot(x="ReleaseMonth", y="Rating", data=df)
if gr.???:
    plt.savefig(fig1.png)
```

Comment: A bar chart will have bars if there is data to be charted. Just check if your `x` and `y` values have data. Of course you could make mistakes such as setting up your axes so that the data is not in a visible range or making the bars invisible ... I would consider such things a coding error rather than "no bars" though.

Comment: I am doing this in a loop for a huge data set and I do not want to save the figure if the plot for the specific choice of data is empty. So, if there is a way to check "if there is data" and not save the figure if there is not, I'd appreciate to learn it.

Comment: In python you check if you have data by checking your data: in this case I would try `if df["ReleaseMonth"].empty`.  If you have problems with blanks, empty string, NaN's etc. you might need a more complex check. See: [python-how-can-i-check-if-the-content-of-one-entire-column-of-a-dataframe-is-e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557405/python-how-can-i-check-if-the-content-of-one-entire-column-of-a-dataframe-is-e)

Answer (score 0):

A plot is only missing bars if no data is provided. You can check that data exists for both axes and then save the plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
gr = sns.barplot(x="ReleaseMonth", y="Rating", data=df)
if not df.dropna(how='all').empty:
    plt.savefig(fig1.png)
```